# how to change page title in angular2 router

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to change the page title from the router, can this be done?

```
import {RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/home', component: HomeCmp, name: 'HomeCmp' }
])
class MyApp {}
```

Comment: Use the [Title service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/Title-class.html). I know there's an answer over there but can't find it.

Comment: New link to `Title` service: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644314/changing-the-page-title-using-the-angular-2-new-router

Comment: I had same problem and the best answer I found was confirmed answer for this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644314/changing-the-page-title-using-the-angular-2-new-router

Comment: New link to Title service https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Answer (score 60):

The [`Title` service @EricMartinez points out](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html) has a `setTitle()` method - that's all you need to set the title.

In terms of doing it automatically on route changes, *as of now* there's no built-in way of doing this other than subscribing to [`Router`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html) and calling `setTitle()` in your callback:

```
import {RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {Title} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/home', component: HomeCmp, name: 'HomeCmp' }
])
class MyApp {
    constructor(router:Router, title:Title) {
       router.events.subscribe((event)=>{ //fires on every URL change
          title.setTitle(getTitleFor(router.url));
       });
    }
 }
```

That said, I emphasize *as of now* because the router is still under heavy development, and I expect (or at least hope) that we'll be able to do this via `RouteConfig` in the final release.

EDIT:

As of the release of Angular 2 (2.0.0), a few things have changed:

- The docs for the `Title` service are now here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Title-class.html
- The service is imported from `'@angular/platform-browser'`

Comment: Also `router.subscribe` is now `router.events.subscribe` in Angular2

Comment: `getTitleFor(url)` this method returns what ? i.e value of `name` in router config ?

Comment: If I'm reading the docs correctly, `getTitleFor()` is no longer a thing.

Comment: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38652281/1221537) to be a bit more detailed

Answer (score 18):

Here's my approach which works fine, especially for nested routes:

I use a recursive helper method to grab the deepest available title after a route has changed:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title | async}}</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.title = this.router.events
      .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.getDeepestTitle(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root));
  }

  title: Observable<string>;

  private getDeepestTitle(routeSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    var title = routeSnapshot.data ? routeSnapshot.data['title'] : '';
    if (routeSnapshot.firstChild) {
      title = this.getDeepestTitle(routeSnapshot.firstChild) || title;
    }
    return title;
  }
}
```

This is assuming, that you have assigned page titles within the data property of your routes, like this:

```
{
  path: 'example',
  component: ExampleComponent,
  data: {
    title: 'Some Page'
  }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for the data property at `router.routeSnapshot.root.data`, but it appears that it can be nested based on how the route is setup. This answer worked for me.

Comment: I had to add `this.title = this.getDeepestTitle(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.root);` for this to work on the first visit.

Answer (score 13):

**For Angular 4+:**

If you want to use route custom data to define page title for every route path, the following approach will work for the nested routes and with angular version 4+:

You can pass page title in your route definition:

```
  {path: 'home', component: DashboardComponent, data: {title: 'Home Pag'}},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutUsComponent, data: {title: 'About Us Page'}},
  {path: 'contact', component: ContactUsComponent, data: {title: 'Contact Us Pag'}},
```

**Now, most important** in your upper level component (ie `AppComponent`), you can globally catch the route custom data on every route change and update the page title:

```
    import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";
    import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(
            private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
            private router: Router, 
            private titleService: Title
        ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router
   .events.pipe(
   filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
   map(() => {
     let child = this.activatedRoute.firstChild;
     while (child) {
       if (child.firstChild) {
         child = child.firstChild;
       } else if (child.snapshot.data && child.snapshot.data['title']) {
         return child.snapshot.data['title'];
       } else {
         return null;
       }
     }
     return null;
   })).subscribe( (title: any) => {
      this.titleService.setTitle(title);
  });
}
```

The above code is tested against angular verion 4+.

Comment: Great! Just some more additions. Be sure to add `import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';` and set the `providers: [Title]` in the Module, and also have to add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` in the Component. Otherwise you can get some errors.

Answer (score 11):

Its really very easy to do this, you can follow therse steps to see the immediate effects:

we provide the Title service in bootstrap:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then import this service in the component you want:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template:
  `<p>
    Select a title to set on the current HTML document:
  </p>

  <ul>
    <li><a (click)="setTitle( 'Good morning!' )">Good morning</a>.</li>
    <li><a (click)="setTitle( 'Good afternoon!' )">Good afternoon</a>.</li>
    <li><a (click)="setTitle( 'Good evening!' )">Good evening</a>.</li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
  }
}
```

now click on those links to see the title changing.

you can also use ng2-meta for changing page title and description as well,you can refer to this link:

https://github.com/vinaygopinath/ng2-meta

Comment: yeah superb answer, using this we can change title and description as well , No need to use `Title` service of angular2 extra in your code, thanks for answer.

Comment: @PardeepJain Will this solution work even though my app takes 4 seconds to load? 
I've used ng2-meta and that doesn't work because of my app loading time. (I've tried everything to reduce the loading time)

Comment: What if user enter the page url and press enter OR Refresh the page, will it work. I can see you copy the same code from document :) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html

Answer (score 5):

Angular 2 provides a [Title Service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html) see Shailesh answer is just copy of that code.

I our app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
........
providers: [..., Title],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Now move to our app.component.ts

```
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';
......
export class AppComponent {

    public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

    public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
      this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
    }
}
```

Put the title tag on your component html and it will read and set for you.

If you want to know how to set it dynamically and [further detail see this article](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1210/angular-2-page-title-static-and-dynamic-with-built-in-title-service)

Answer (score 3):

```
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser"; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers : [Title]
})

export class AppComponent implements {
   constructor( private title: Title) { 
     this.title.setTitle('page title changed');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I went with:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private title: Title) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.title.setTitle(this.recursivelyGenerateTitle(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root).join(' - '));
        }
    });
}

recursivelyGenerateTitle(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    var titleParts = <string[]>[];
    if (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.firstChild) {
            titleParts = titleParts.concat(this.recursivelyGenerateTitle(snapshot.firstChild));
        }

        if (snapshot.data['title']) {
            titleParts.push(snapshot.data['title']);
        }
    }

    return titleParts;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, only tweak I made was to ensure a title on the HTML document and tweaked this line of your code (note the `reverse()`), `this.title.setTitle(this.title.getTitle().split(' - ')[0] + ' - ' + this.recursivelyGenerateTitle(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root).reverse().join(' - '));`.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could use `unshift()` instead of `push()` and then `reverse()`.

Answer (score 3):

**Angular 6+**
I have modify the old code using new Pipe() and its working fine.

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { filter, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

...

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    public titleService: Title,
  ) {
    this.setTitle();
  }
```

....

```
setTitle() {
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => this.activatedRoute),
    map((route: any) => {
      while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
      return route;
    }),
    filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
    mergeMap((route: any) => route.data)).subscribe((event) => {
      this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']);
      console.log('Page Title', event['title']);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest way to change the Title of the page, when pages/views are navigated (Tested as of Angular @2.3.1). Simply apply the following solution to all the views you have and you should be good to go:

**Example Code in About Us page/view:**

```
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";

export class AboutUsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _titleService: Title) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //Set page Title when this view is initialized
    this._titleService.setTitle('About Us');
  }

}
```

**Example Code in Contact Us page/view:**

```
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";

export class ContactusComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _titleService: Title) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //Set page Title
    this._titleService.setTitle('Contact Us');
  }

}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend this answer

Answer (score 2):

In the below example:

-We added object of data: { title: 'NAME' } to any routing object.

-We set a basic name ("CTM") for uploading time (when clicking F5 for Refreash..): `<title>CTM</title>`.

-We added "TitleService" class.

-we handle Routher events by filtering them from app.component.ts.

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>CTM</title>
  </head>
```

...

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TitleService }   from './shared/title.service';
...


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
..
  ],
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
...
  ],
  providers: [
      TitleService,
...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }

enableProdMode();
```

**title.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable()
export class TitleService extends Title {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }


    private recursivelyGenerateTitle(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        var titleParts = <string[]>[];
        if (snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.firstChild) {
                titleParts = this.recursivelyGenerateTitle(snapshot.firstChild);
            }

            if (snapshot.data['title']) {
                titleParts.push(snapshot.data['title']);
            }
        }

        return titleParts;
    }

    public CTMGenerateTitle(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        this.setTitle("CTM | " + this.recursivelyGenerateTitle(snapshot).join(' - '));
    }

}
```

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { MainComponent } from './components/main.component';

import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard }          from './shared/auth/auth-guard.service';
import { AuthService }    from './shared/auth/auth.service';


export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { title: 'Main' } },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [
..
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const componentsOfAppRoutingModule = [MainComponent];
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { TitleService } from './shared/title.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ctm-app',
  template: `
    <!--<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/']">Rooting</a>-->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router, private titleService: TitleService) {

        this.router.events.filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe((event) => {
            console.log("AppComponent.constructor: Setting HTML document's Title");
            this.titleService.CTMGenerateTitle(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root);
        });

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Working fine in Angular 6 and 6+ with Pipe and map  method instead of using filter**

**Step1**: routing setup

```
{path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: {title: 'My Dashboard'}},
{path: 'aboutUs', component: AboutUsComponent, data: {title: 'About Us'}},
{path: 'contactUs', component: ContactUsComponent, data: {title: 'Contact Us Page'}},
```

**step2:** in your app.module.ts import module

```
import { BrowserModule, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

then in provider add providers: `[title]`

**Step 3**
    **In your main component import**

```
import { Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouterModule, ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor(private titleService: Title, private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

ngOnInit() {

    this.router.events.pipe(map(() => {
        let child = this.activatedRoute.firstChild;
        while (child) {
            if (child.firstChild) {
                child = child.firstChild;
            } else if (child.snapshot.data && child.snapshot.data['title']) {
                return child.snapshot.data['title'];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    })).subscribe(title => {
        this.titleService.setTitle(title);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommend [@ngx-meta/core](https://github.com/ngx-meta/core) plugin plugin that I've just released, in the case if you're looking for a method to set page title and meta tags dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 6+**

*if route configured as follow :-*

```
Routes = [
     {  path: 'dashboard',
       component: DashboardComponent,
       data: {title: 'Dashboard'}
   }]
```

**Then in component constructor title can be set as follow :- **

```
 constructor( private _titleService: Title, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    activatedRoute.data.pipe(map(data => data.title)).subscribe(x => this._titleService.setTitle(x));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple generic way to set the title:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private titleService: Title
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        const { title } = this.activatedRoute.firstChild.snapshot.data;
        this.titleService.setTitle(title);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

where `title` needs to be set on each route like:

```
{ path: '', component: WelcomeComponent, data: {title: 'Welcome to my app'} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, If you are using Angular **Version** greater than **14.0** you can simply put title in Routes array, Like -

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
path: 'home',
component: HomeComponent,
title: "'My App - Home' // <-- Page title"
  },
  {
path: 'about',
component: AboutComponent,
title: "'My App - About Me'  // <-- Page title"
  }
];
```