# Angular2 - SEO - how to manipulate the meta description

Tags: seo, angular, meta-tags

Search Results in google are displayed via TitleTag and the `<meta name="description"..."/>` Tag.
The `<title>`-Tag is editiable via Angular2 [how to change page title in angular2 router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602806/how-to-change-page-title-in-angular2-router)

What's left is the description.

Is it possibile to write a directive in angular2, that manipulates the meta-tags in the `<head>` part of my page.
So depending on the selected route, the meta description changes like:

```
<meta name="description" content="**my description for this route**"/>
```

Answer (score 39):

Since Angular4, you can use [Angular Meta service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Meta-class.html).

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// [...]

constructor(private meta: Meta) {}

// [...]

this.meta.addTag({ name: 'robots', content: 'noindex' });
```

Comment: Will this help google index the title and meta tags correctly?

Comment: The tags added/updated via Meta doesn't get picked by the crawler, is there a way around to this?

Comment: I imagine that this must be destined for use with Angular Universal.

Comment: sorry, Actually I dont understand, inwhich file, I have to update this code.

Comment: This works with Angular Universal. Here are the changes I made: https://github.com/kmturley/universal-starter/commit/5a34a8cfd127cc01e5676e30c1c515d193c837c1

Answer (score 14):

It is possible. I implemented it in my app and below I provide the description how it is made.

The basic idea is to use `Meta` from `@angular/platform-browser`

To dynamically change particular meta tag you have to:

1. Remove the old one using `removeTag(attrSelector: string) : void`
   method.
2. Add the new one using `addTag(tag: MetaDefinition, forceCreation?:
   boolean) : HTMLMetaElement` method.

And you have to do it when the router fires route change event.

Notice: In fact it is also necessary to have default `<title>...</title>` and `<meta name="description"..." content="..."/>` in head of index.html so before it is set dynamically there is already some static content.

My `app-routing.module.ts` content:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { StringComparisonComponent }  from '../module-string-comparison/string-comparison.component';
import { ClockCalculatorComponent }  from '../module-clock-calculator/clock-calculator.component';

import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/string-comparison', pathMatch: 'full',
    data: { title: 'String comparison title', metaDescription: 'String comparison meta description content' }
  },
  {
    path: 'string-comparison',  component: StringComparisonComponent,
    data: { title: 'String comparison title', metaDescription: 'String comparison meta description content' }
  },
  {
    path: 'clock-time-calculator',  component: ClockCalculatorComponent,
    data: { title: 'Clock time calculator title', metaDescription: 'Clock time calculator meta description content' }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private titleService: Title,
    private metaService: Meta
  ){
    //Boilerplate code to filter out only important router events and to pull out data object field from each route
    this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
    .map(route => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
    })
    .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')
    //Data fields are merged so we can use them directly to take title and metaDescription for each route from them
    .mergeMap(route => route.data)
    //Real action starts there
    .subscribe((event) => {
        //Changing title
        this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']);

        //Changing meta with name="description"
        var tag = { name: 'description', content: event['metaDescription'] };
        let attributeSelector : string = 'name="description"';
        this.metaService.removeTag(attributeSelector);
        this.metaService.addTag(tag, false);
    });
  }

}
```

1. As it can be seen there is an additional `data` object field for
   each route.   It contains `title` and `metaDescription` strings
   which will be used as title and meta tag content.
2. In constructor we filter out router events and we subscribe to filtered
   router event. Rxjs is used there, but in fact it is not necessary to use it. Regular `if statements` and `loops` could be used insead of stream, filter and map.
3. We also merge our data object field with our event so we can easily
   use info like `title` and `metaDescription` strings.
4. We dynamically change `<title>...</title>` and `<meta name="description"..." content="..."/>` tags.

Effects:

First component
[image: String comparison title and meta description tags]

Second component
[image: Clock time calculator title and meta description tags]

In fact I currently use a little bit more sophisticated version of this solution which uses also [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) to show different title and meta description for different languages.
Full code is available in [angular2-bootstrap-translate-website-starter](https://github.com/lukedd3/angular2-bootstrap-translate-website-starter) project.
The `app-routing.module.ts` file with ngx-translate solution is exactly there: [app-routing.module.ts](https://github.com/lukedd3/angular2-bootstrap-translate-website-starter/blob/master/src/app/routing/app-routing.module.ts).

There is also the production app which uses the same solution: http://www.online-utils.com.

For sure it is not the only way and there might be better ways to do it. But I tested this solution and it works.

In fact the solution is very similar to this from corresponding post about changing title: [How to change page title in angular2 router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602806/how-to-change-page-title-in-angular2-router).

Angular Meta docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Meta-class.html. In fact they aren't very informative and I had to experiment and look into real .js code to make this dynamic meta change working.

Comment: I tried this tags are getting added but on facebook on facebook open graph it doesn't shows. it there any way to work around ?

Answer (score 6):

I have developed and just released [@ngx-meta/core](https://github.com/ngx-meta/core) plugin, which manipulates the meta tags at the route level, and allows setting the meta tags programmatically within the component constructor.

You can find detailed instructions at [@ngx-meta/core](https://github.com/ngx-meta/core) github repository. Also, source files might be helpful to introduce a custom logic.

Comment: I have launched into live ng2-metadata and it works fine but when I get google to crawl my pages it still says I have duplicate meta tags. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: I think you should have been removed "static" tags from your html. ng2-metadata will write them on the fly.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Thanks alot!

Comment: I found this doesnt work @RonaldPadur when lazy loaded routes are used

Comment: @AngularM lazy loaded routes are a big isssue in angular, especially when you compile the app in AoT using ngtools. Angular team is working on issues with it.

Comment: @BurakTasci I'm using your plugin to change title and my meta data for each of my routes. But the google bots wont show the title or meta description in google search. They use the default index.html pages title and meta tags for each route. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @AngularM you need server-side rendering in order that Google shows meta information that you set dynamically. I've done it using Angular Universal, explained it on [this article](https://medium.com/burak-tasci/angular-4-with-server-side-rendering-aka-angular-universal-f6c228ded8b0) and published a repo at https://github.com/ng-seed/universal

Comment: @BurakTasci my website is client side only and hosted with Firebase. So I cant use that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @AngularM unfortunately this is not possible due to architectural limitations of SPA's. Same in React, Vue as well as in Angular. You need to run your Angular app on Express or IIS.

Comment: Angular Universal was exactly built to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no out-of-the-box solution only an open issue to implement it https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7438.

You can of course implement something like the title service yourself, just use the [TitleService](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3c8fa8c50d820e3317bc40292c73df03c8b23e86/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/title.ts) as template

A `Meta` service similar to `Title` service is in the works (currently only a pull request).

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I will go with the title service approach

Comment: Has this changed in the release version? I know there is a built in title service in platform-browser but is there anything for the description?

Comment: Nope, nothing changed so far.

Comment: This PR has now been merged and is part of 4.0.0-beta.0