# Display route title inside root component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a root component and want to display route title inside special section in it.
I can detect which route is active in every component.
However, I don`t know how to do it inside root component.

This code shows title fine in ChildComponent1 :

```
route:ActivatedRoute
ngOnInit() {

        this.route.data.subscribe(
            data => console.log(data)
        )

    }
```

How can I detect what is current route`s title and display it inside the root component?

```
export const routes: Routes = [

  {path: '', component: Component1, canActivate: [NonAuthGuard]},

  {
    path: 'root', component: rootcomponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
    {
      path: 'Child1',
      component: ChildComponent1,
      data: {
        title: 'Child1'
      },
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
    },
     {
      path: 'Child2',
      component: ChildComponent2,
      data: {
        title: 'Child2'
      },
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
    },
]}
```

Comment: UPD: Found the answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644314/changing-the-page-title-using-the-angular-2-new-router

Answer (score 0):

You could inject `Router` in your root component and then subscribe its **events**.
Example:

```
constructor(private router : Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(event.url);
        }
    });
}
```

You should check if your event is instance of `NavigationStart` or `NavigationEnd`, because your event will fire *several* times.

Comment: And how should I access route`s data title? Event object contains only id and urls.  {id: 1, url: "/url/url1", urlAfterRedirects: "/url/url1"}

Comment: what do you mean by route's data title?

Comment: I provided my array of routes(routes constant) which describes how to navigate inside application. Each route has data field with title attribute.