# Subscribe to data change in Angular 2 based on route navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Suppose I have the following routes:

```
[
    {
        path: 'view',
        children: [
            {

                path: ':id',
                component: CustomerViewComponent,
                resolve: {
                    customerViewData: CustomerResolve,
                    edit: ViewRouteResolve // Returns false
                },
                data: {
                    other: false
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'edit',
                        resolve: {
                            edit: EditRouteResolve // Returns true
                        },
                        data: {
                            other: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        data: {
                            other: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    { path: '', component: CustomerListComponent }
]
```

I want to use the `CustomerViewComponent` for /view/ and /view/1/edit

The problem is I am unable to catch this data change in my component. I have tried with the `resolve` or `data` and I can't catch any changes...

This code will not trigger as expected:

```
this.route.data.subscribe(m => {
    debugger; // Triggers only once the view loads, then never again
});

// This triggers quite often, but the data is always stale.
this.router.events.subscribe(m => {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.data['edit']);
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.data['other']);
    debugger;
});
```

Could this be a bug? my only work around is to look at the event NavigationEnd and analyze the .url string property...

Comment: The solution is rather simple, no need to use any events. I added an answer below where I explain why not, and how you instead can get your latest data. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 8):

When listening to `router.events` the subscribe callback will get a few different types of events, multiple per route change. The `ActivationStart` is the one that holds the route `data`. Something like the following helped me:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof ActivationStart) {
    let data = event.snapshot.data;
    this.titleService.setTitle(data['title'] || '_your_default_title_');
  }
})
```

Comment: That sort of works. But ActivationStart is triggered way before we know if the user actually ends up on the route in question, doesn't it?

Comment: No need to use route events in a component. You can simply subscribe to `route.data` observable which will re-emit with the latest data on route changes.

Answer (score 5):

Try instead to use `ActivatedRoute` from `@angular/router`

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params['edit']);
    console.log(params['other']);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. `this.route` is actually the `ActivatedRoute` already and I am not looking at the `params` but the `data`.

Comment: Oh, right. Then check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38652281/3159399

Comment: Wow, this is such an ugly design... I have been browsing the bugs on GitHub and they all close them by design. There are multiple people reporting the same problem... This is a design issue.

Answer (score 1):

I will comment on the second part of your question:

> *This triggers quite often, but the data is always stale*

In case you want to use routing events, You can listen to any of [these events](https://angular.io/api/router). But in your particular case you are only interested in `NavigationEnd`. You can solve that by filtering the emitted value from the events observable using a `pipe` and a `filter` operator, so that your observer will only run on `NavigationEnd`:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event instanceof NavigationEnd),
).subscribe(event => {
  //... do something on navigation end...
});
```

Since you still used `this.route.snapshot.data` in your observer, your data will not change or in your words be "stale" (no matter the event), it will refer always to the same static data, the data when `ngOnInit` was first called. 
Since the component is the same even after the route changes the component will not be destroyed and recreated, so `ngOnInit` will not be called again.

This could be solved by using the `ActivatedRoute` data observable `route.data` instead of the `route.snapshot.data`. You would have to subscribe or in case of your events solution you could use a `mergeMap` operator:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  mergeMap(this.route.data),
).subscribe(data => {
  //...do something with your data...
});
```

But, since you are actually in a component you do **NOT** need to use any events, the data from the `ActivatedRoute` instance observable will automatically re-emit the latest values on successful route navigation. So I suggest you more or less go with the answer from @DanielKucal which already suggests using the active route which is the right way. Just change the `params` from his answer to `data` and you will have your latest data:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
    //...Do something with your data here...
  }  
}
```