# How to get current route custom data in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have set up routes is like below

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: ListingComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home Page',
      module:'list'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];
```

now when i come to `'/list'`  route then on `'listing.component.ts'` i have written below code

```
export class ListingComponent {

  public constructor(private router:Router) {
      //here how i can get **data** of **list** routes

  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644314/changing-the-page-title-using-the-angular-2-new-router/38652281#38652281

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```js
public constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) {
  console.log(route.snapshot.data['title'])
}
```

Comment: the problem is that this route is not necessary the final route, it's a nested tree. It really depends on where you put this piece, then you are just play your luck here.

Comment: This won't always give you the correct results as it depends on where you're  placing it.

Comment: Right, if you don't add it to the component that was added by the current route, you need to traverse the router tree to get the desired segment to be able to access the data.

Comment: this doesnt work if you want the data on indetph ActivatedRoute on the routerState tree

Answer (score 41):

**For Angular 4+**

If you place the following code in the parent or upper level components like `AppComponent` then it won't work. It only works on child or lower level components for which you've defined the route custom data:

```
 public constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) {
      console.log(route.snapshot.data['title']);
  }
```

So, if you want to access the route custom data globally from a parent or upper level component to access the change in the route custom data then you've to listen to router events particularly `RoutesRecognized` or `NavigationEnd` events. I'm gonna show two procedures with `AppComponent` with two events:

**First Approach:**

```
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.router
        .events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => {
          let child = this.activatedRoute.firstChild;
          while (child) {
            if (child.firstChild) {
              child = child.firstChild;
            } else if (child.snapshot.data && child.snapshot.data['custom_data']) {
              return child.snapshot.data['custom_data'];
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
          return null;
        }).subscribe( (customData: any) => {
          console.log(customData);
       });
    }
 }
```

**Second Approach is using:**

```
this.router.events
.filter(event => event instanceof RoutesRecognized)
.map( (event: RoutesRecognized) => {
    return event.state.root.firstChild.data['custom_data'];
})
.subscribe(customData => {
    console.log(customData);
});
```

**Note:** Even though last one is shorter and usually works, but, if you have nested routes then it is encouraged to use the first one.

Comment: Great, your first approach helped a lot. Thank you! For the others: You have to import "rxjs/add/operator/filter" and "rxjs/add/operator/map" to make it work

Answer (score 15):

After I tested various solution, the angular support group answer actually solved this problem nicely.

[ActivatedRoute doesn't carry data](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11812#issuecomment-248820529), and here's the solution for detecting the page variable within the `data: { page: 'login' }`.

```typescript
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent {
  page = '';
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // listen to page variable from router events
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        let route = event.state.root.firstChild;
        this.page = 'page-' + route.data.page || '';
        console.log('Page', this.page);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @windmaomao - based on your answer I was able to answer the same question related to Angular 6: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912789/angular-6-unable-to-retrieve-static-data/51009699#51009699

Answer (score 12):

asmmahmud's Answer works well till Angular 5.x
but 6.X breaks the `this.router.events` since rxjs 6.x has breaking changes. So just came across an update:

```
import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {map, mergeMap} from 'rxjs/internal/operators';

router.events
          .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
            map(() => {
              let route = activatedRoute.firstChild;
              let child = route;
              while (child) {
                if (child.firstChild) {
                  child = child.firstChild;
                  route = child;
                } else {
                  child = null;
                }
              }
              return route;
            }),
            mergeMap(route => route.data)
          )
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
          });
```

Answer (score 9):

its work for component that not navigate (like header)  :

```
this.route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data['title']
```

and complete example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';


export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.title = this.route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data['title']
      }
    });
  }    
}
```

cerdit to this [answare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43513784/7452985)

Answer (score 4):

For those that are now using Angular 6+ and latest RXJS 6 here is something based on the ansers above:

Routing example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: {title: 'Home'}},
  // {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: {title: 'Login'}},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: {title: 'Dashboard'}, canActivate: [AppAuthGuard]},
  {path: 'eventDetails', component: EventCardComponent, data: {title: 'Details'}},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

How to get the title example:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.routerEventSubscription = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof RoutesRecognized))
      .pipe(map((event: RoutesRecognized) => {
        return event.state.root.firstChild.data['title'];
      })).subscribe(title => {
        this.title = title;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to have current route data, can get it from [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)

```
public constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log((activatedRoute.data as any).value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

2021

[Research Router events](https://medium.com/@TheAkshayKolte/angular-routing-events-e914478c9c) for deeper knowledge on complex routing info.

But most of the time don't overthink it.

```typescript
// 1. Subscribe in constructor to get events (OnInit and later are too late)
constructor(private router: Router) {
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    // 2. Start with ActivationEnd, experiment with the other events
    if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
        // 3. if your data exists assign it for use!
        if (event.snapshot.data['searchSubject']) {
            this.searchSubject = event.snapshot.data['searchSubject'];
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to ActivatedRoute.data. This is somehow similar to the answer from @dinesh-kumar, but I believe `(activatedRoute.data as any).value` is quite a hack taking advantage of the fact, that `activatedRoute.data` is implemented as a BehaviorSubject. But the [ActivatedRoute.data](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) is exposed as `Observable<Data>`, so the correct way would be to subscribe (don't forget to unsubscribe, or `take(1)` etc.) or use `async` pipe etc.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After I tried a lot, I found the best solution

```
  private ngUnsubscribe$ = new Subject();

    constructor (private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    
     ngOnInit () {
        const routeEndEvent$ = this.router.events
          .pipe(
            filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
            tap(() => console.warn("END")),
        );
    
        this.router.events
          .pipe(
            filter(e => e instanceof ChildActivationEnd && e.snapshot.component === this.route.component),
            buffer(routeEndEvent$),
            map(([ev]) => (ev as ChildActivationEnd).snapshot.firstChild.data),
            takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$)
          )
          .subscribe(childRoute => {
            console.log('childRoute', childRoute);
          })
      }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the many existing answers this question already has, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in app.component.ts (ng 5)

```
 constructor(
    private router: Router,
) {

 router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
       this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent);
    });
}

checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event): void {
    if (routerEvent instanceof ActivationStart) {
        if (routerEvent.snapshot.data.custom_data) {
            this.currentpage = routerEvent.snapshot.data['custom_data'];
            console.log('4.' + this.currentpage);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Great! It's working here! Thanks! One doubt, how can I get data when I access direct in router?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
        this.pageTitle = this.titleService.getTitle();
        // check instanceof  ChildActivationEnd  || ChildActivationStart
        if (event instanceof ChildActivationStart) {
            let pageIcon = event.snapshot?.firstChild?.children[0]?.data['icon'];
            this.pageIcon = pageIcon ? pageIcon : this.pageIcon;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution which works for me:

```
const routerData$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(e => e instanceof ActivationEnd),
  throttleTime(0),
  map((e: ActivationEnd) => e.snapshot.data));
const urlAfterRedirects$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map((navEnd: NavigationEnd) => navEnd.urlAfterRedirects));

urlAfterRedirects$.pipe(withLatestFrom(routerData$))
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```