# Binding routerLink html to route data

Tags: angular

In Angular 8, for

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'page', component: MyPageComponent, data: {title: "Page"} }
];
```

how can I bind route.data.title in HTML?

```
<a routerLink="/page">{{???.data.title}}</a>
```

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40863833/6444705) could help ?

Comment: @Emilien The problem with this is that you need the title up front, before that route becomes the activated route

Comment: unfortunately, ActivatedRoute is available **after** the route navigation

Comment: All your `<a ...></a>` tags are in a *ngFor ?

Comment: Some are in, some are static.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution (at least in my case, it depends on how you declare your routes).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to query the routes themselves (which is done easily after a routing event), I would store page names in one place:

```
export const appTitles = {
  myPage: 'Page'
};

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'page', component: MyPageComponent, data: {title: appTitles.myPage} }
];
```

Component HTML:

```
<a routerLink="/page">{{title}}</a>
```

Component ts:

```
title = appTitles.myPage;
```

EDIT:

I store my routes in their own object:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '/home', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: 'Home' }
    }
];
```

I could probably achieve what you want to by creating a service that queries and caches the data.title by url, e.g.:

```
export class RouteTitleService {

  private cache = {};

  getTitle(path: string): string {
    if (this.cache.hasOwnProperty(path)) {
      return this.cache[path];
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < appRoutes.length; i++) {
      // TODO: common function for querying an array of routes
      string title = this.getTitleFromRoute(appRoutes[i], path);
      if (typeof(title) === 'string') {
        this.cache[path] = title;
        return title;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  private getTitleFromRoute(route: Route, path: string): string {
    if (route.path === path) {
      return route.data ? route.data.title : '';
    }

    if (route.children) {
      if (let i = 0; i < route.children.length; i++) {
        string title = this.getTitleFromRoute(route.children[i], path);
        if (typeof(title) === 'string') {
          return title;
        }
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

NB, this is not tested, and may not be relevant to your case, but it's something I may think about doing properly.

My app routing module is then simple:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer },
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to reduce copy-paste of `data: {title: "**Page**"}` to `<a...>**Page**</a>`. In your code instead `path: '**page**'...` is copied to `appTitles.my**Page**`, trading copy-paste for copy-paste. Imagine an app having 50+ routes, its a very error-prone approach

Comment: I get your point. I must say, I've often thought about looking into this, but I've never needed to get route titles up front, only after navigation, which becomes fairly trivial.

Comment: I store my routes in their own object, and could theoretically traverse the hierarchy to find the title, matching by url. I could then cache the titles by url to avoid multiple recursions. Does that make sense?