# Obtain Route information given any url in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular10

In Angular 10 I have the following entry inside my routes:

```js
const routes = [
  { path:'my/target/:targetId', component: MyTargetComponent, data: { dataKey: 'dataValue} },
   ...
]
```

From *anywhere* inside my application, given any path (say `my/target/55`) I need to be able to access all information contained inside the Route object that I used to define such route (in particular I need to read the `data` field). Is there a built-in function in Angular 10 to do this?

**UPDATE**: I need to access information for urls that are NOT necessarily the url of the current page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current route custom data in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863664/how-to-get-current-route-custom-data-in-angular-2)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I've updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

The Angular Router will pass the dynamic data. supose, data:{ id:'1', name:"Angular10"} when the MyTargetComponent is rendered. The data value will be located in the data property of the ActivatedRoute service

We can then read the data by subscribing to the activatedroute.data property as shown below:

```
   ngOnInit() { 
   this.activatedroute.data.subscribe(data => {
       this.product=data;
   }) }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try like this

```
constructor(private route: Router) {}
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router);
    // on console expand this object and will get all details of routes of complete application in **this.router.config** object.
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, I've updated my question with more details.