# How to get parameter from route send from AngularJS to Angular 11

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a hybrid app which is actually upgraded from AngularJS to Angular 11 and some modules are still in progress to be upgraded.

So to route to an Angular 11 module from AngularJS I am using:

```
$state.go('checkuser', {userid: userid});
```

Now I want to catch `userid` in my component HTML and in my TypeScript file, but I'm unable to find a way to do so.

Here is how I am trying to catch the variable:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {StateService} from '@uirouter/angularjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'ts-checkuser',
  templateUrl: './checkuser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkuser.component.scss']
})
export class checkuserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private $state: StateService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.$state);
  }
```

Comment: check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863664/how-to-get-current-route-custom-data-in-angular-2/46305085"

Comment: @RaviAshara this is purely for angular. Not for angularjs