# How to access route 'data' on route-change, in Angular 2

Tags: angular

My route is declared like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'somepath',
        component: SomeComponent,
        canActivate: [LoginGuard],
        data: {
            showSidebar: true
        }
    }
];
```

Then, later on, in my NgModule imports, i load the route like this:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ...
]
```

I'm wondering how I can access the `data.showSidebar` flag on route-change?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute) {
  route.data.forEach(data => console.log(data.showSidebar));
}
```

See also [Changing the page title using the Angular 2 new router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644314/changing-the-page-title-using-the-angular-2-new-router/38652281#38652281)

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to work. `showSidebar` does not exist on the `data` object, as defined this way.

Comment: Nope, I need it in the main `AppComponent`.

Comment: You can try `route.firstChild.data...`

Comment: That seemed a bit 'hacky'. I ended up creating a service through which I detect whether the sidebar should be visible. Thanks, anyways.