# Angular-Router 4.0.0 possibility to save any data to routerState

Tags: angular, router, breadcrumbs

Is it possible to save any data to a routerState?

I want to implement breadcrumbs in my application and I think it would be very nice to save the breadcrumb data, which I am going to present, in the routerState.

Comment: What is breadcrumb data? You can add static data to routes, and you can use route parameters and query parameters. Besides that you can't store data with routes.

Comment: I want to add a string to a router state ( { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent } ) and then somewhere in the app query this data with this.router.routerState...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488565/angular-2-check-current-active-route-name/41542652#41542652