# Check if router-outlet is in use

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

All,

I would like to use `*ngIf` to remove a section of a page if a specific `router-outlet` has a component.

I've tried searching through `ActivatedRoute` and `Router`, but I can't seem to figure it out. How do you check if a specific `router-outlet` is in use?

Comment: Hopefully this will help you.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488565/angular-2-check-current-active-route-name

Comment: @AvinashT. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

Can be solved like this:

```
<div [hidden]="!myOutlet.isActivated">
  <router-outlet name="my-outlet" #myOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

No changes in component class needed.

Comment: Why can't I do like this----html : <router-outlet #myOutlet></router-outlet> ts:@ViewChild('myOutlet') myOutlet: RouterOutlet   .When I want to use myOutlet, it's a nativeElement, not an RouterOutlet

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out. You need to use the events for router outlets. However, you can't use `ngIf` because events won't be fired unless the outlet is in the dom.

**ts**

```
showOutlet: boolean;

onActivate(event : any) {
  this.showOutlet = true;
}

onDeactivate(event : any) {
  this.showOutlet = false;
}
```

**html**

```
<div [hidden]="!showOutlet">
  <router-outlet name="my-outlet"
      (activate)="onActivate($event)"
      (deactivate)="onDeactivate($event)"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: out of curiosity what is the use-case when you would hide a `router-outlet`?

Comment: I have an interface using Project Clarity. Sometimes I want to use the side-nav (dashboard), other times I want to use the sub-nav (search). 
I have each section set up as a different router-outlet to separate concerns.

Answer (score 1):

to check whenever OUTLET is in use, try this one:

```
<router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>

<div *ngIf="!outlet.isActivated">Outlet is EMPTY!</div>
<div *ngIf="outlet.isActivated">Outlet is in use!</div>
```

Comment: Easiest way to hide non router-outlet elements

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get this information from the Angular `Router`.

As of version `@angular/core: 7.2.0`.

**html:**

```
<router-outlet name="myOutlet"></router-outlet>
```

**ts** of any component file:

```
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(
        router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const myOutletIsActive: Observable<boolean> = this.router.events.pipe(
            filter((event: RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
            map(() => this.router.getCurrentNavigation()
                .extractedUrl.root.children.primary.children.myOutlet !== undefined)
        );
        myOutletIsActive.subscribe(isActive => console.log('isActive', isActive));
    }   
}
```

The advantage is that you can retrieve the state of every outlet from every component of your app.