# Angular 2+ - change css based on route

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to build a tab menu in Angular (v2.4.5) . A tab is active based on the route.

For example I have this routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tab1',
    component: Tab1Component,
  },
  {
    path: 'tab2',
    component: Tab2Component,
  }
];
```

if the user enters the address `http://localhost/tab2` I want `tab2` to be highlighted ( change tab css).

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644314/changing-the-page-title-using-the-angular-2-new-router/38652281#38652281

Comment: Have you tried the using the `routerLinkActive` directive on the tab link? I.e. `<a routerLink="tab2" routerLinkActive="active">Tab2</a>`. What you pass to this directive is the name of a CSS class(es) that will get added to the link if it matches the current route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**RouterLinkActive**

> Lets you add a CSS class to an element when the link's route becomes
>   active.

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="class1 class2">Bob</a>
<a routerLink="/user/bob" [routerLinkActive]="['class1', 'class2']">Bob</a>
```

You can assign the RouterLinkActive instance to a template variable and directly check the isActive status also:

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive">
  Bob {{ rla.isActive ? '(already open)' : ''}}
</a>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `routerLinkActive="active"` on your links, you will have something like this:

```
<nav>
      <a routerLink="/tab1" routerLinkActive="active">TAB 1</a>
      <a routerLink="/tab2" routerLinkActive="active">TAB 2</a>
</nav>
```

In your CSS you'll add a `active` class for your nav links:

```
nav {
   color: black;
}
nav .active {
   color: orange;
}
```

More info about routes [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).