# Angular 2 - Routing- Showing different route name in the browser address bar

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it possible to show the state name in the address bar for the specific route in angular 2 and 4. for ex, i have below route configurations,

```
{
 path:"animals",
 component : AnimalComponent,
 children:[{
   path:"cat",
   component:CatComponent
 },{
  path:"dog",
  component:DogComponent
 }]
}
```

it loads CatComponent in AnimalComponent router-outlet when address is "animals/cat" and DogComponent in AnimalComponent router-outlet when address is "animals/dog". Is it possible to show only "cat" in the address bar for the "animals/cat" and "dog" in the address  bar for the "animals/dog" route.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644314/changing-the-page-title-using-the-angular-2-new-router/38652281?s=1|3.2069#38652281 or just set the `title` with some other data.

Comment: See: [Set the Document Title](https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just remove the path from the parent route:

```
{
 path:"",
 component : AnimalComponent,
 children:[{
   path:"cat",
   component:CatComponent
 },{
  path:"dog",
  component:DogComponent
 }]
}
```

angular will automatically link the children to the closest ancestor (or root if there isn't any)

Comment: Thanks for this. Where can i find documentation about this.

Comment: There's a very long section explaining how Angular router works in their official doc: https://angular.io/guide/router
For your concrete case you can take a look to the section called 'Component-less route' in which there's an example quite similar to yours.