# angular2 pass data to route definition

Tags: angular, angular-routing

For my mobile version I need to have different header title for every page, I can do that using header service and set title in each of my component, I also can listen to url changes in my header component and set up title depends on url, but I don't like it. What I really wanna do is to set title in my route definition like this

```
const mobileRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', data: { title: 'login' }, loadChildren: '../mobile/login/login.module#LoginModule' },
];
```

I get this idea from this article about preloading modules https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-preloading-modules-ba3c75e424cb, but I can't get it work for route changes. 2 problems:
1) if I subscribe to route.data, there is no data['title'] (however it works for PreloadingStrategy)

```
this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

2) I don't know how to subscribe to route change in the way to get route object and not events. Is it even possible?

Comment: can you add how you subscribe router data

Comment: @Robert updated

Comment: can you add constructor of component

Comment: var "route" is instance of "Router" or "ActivatedRoute" ???

Comment: @VictorBredihin can you try this route.data.value['title']

Comment: It's all described here in detail: https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating

Comment: thanks guys, I found the problem, for login component data is here, but I need it in my header component. So, I guess it's impossible, right?

Comment: Have you try this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644314/changing-the-page-title-using-the-angular-2-new-router

Comment: @Luke looks great, I think that's it, thanks. Let me try