# How to change title of a page using angular(angular 2 or 4) route?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-cli

I want to change the title of the page whenever I click or browse the link from the URL bar. How to change that using Angular route?
I am using angular version 4 and angular cli.

Comment: *How to change that using Angular route?* By searching for "change page title angular2".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change page title in angular2 router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602806/how-to-change-page-title-in-angular2-router)

Comment: Thanks, but that code was not working, or else I was not able to implement that in my code.

Comment: Then present what you did, and in what particular way it was not working, and/or in what particular way you were not able to implement it in your code.

Answer (score 24):

**You can to use `@angular/plateform-browser` to use the `setTitle()`:**

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-component',
})

export class YourComponent implements onInit {
  constructor(private title: Title) {}

 ngOnInit() {
     this.title.setTitle('Title for this component');
 }

}
```

Comment: Work So EZ Thanks !

Comment: It might be not related to this question, is there a way to change it back after redirecting to other pages other than `setTitle` in all other pages? Since this change will be kept after leaving that page.

Answer (score 14):

you have to pass "title" as data to your route

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'calendar',
  component: CalendarComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'new', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'all', component: CalendarListComponent, data: { title: 'My Calendar' } },
    { path: 'new', component: CalendarEventComponent, data: { title: 'New Calendar Entry' } },
    { path: ':id', component: CalendarEventComponent, data: { title: 'Calendar Entry' } }
  ]
}];
```

Then do this imports in your Component:

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```

Once imported, we can inject them both:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: `
    <div>
      Hello world!
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor( private router: Router,
               private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
               private titleService: Title) {}
}
```

To update a page title statically, we can simply call setTitle like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.router.events
        .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
        .map((route) => {
            while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
            return route;
        })
        .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
        .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
        .subscribe((event) => {
            let title = 'Default Title Here'
            if(event['title']) {
                title = event['title'];
            }
            this.titleService.setTitle(title);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to know that, is this the complete code for changing the title? I implemented this but still I was not able to change the title. As I am a beginner in angular, can you send me the complete code?

Comment: see the following for the full code:
https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

Comment: -1: The `data: { title: '...'}` is not used in this example and so it does not answer the question directly. Seems like a fast copy paste from the link @JKing provided

Comment: -1 also. At least give credit where you copy pasted this answer. https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with following way with few lines of code, hope it will help you.

You can pass any name in the data object of routes variable (**app-routing.module.ts**) as follows

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: Component,
    data: {
      page_title: 'Title of your page'
    }

  }
]
```

Then fetch the value of page_title in the data object of the routes into the **app.component.ts** and set as title.

```
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
export class AppComponent {
  page_title = '';
  constructor(private titleService: Title, private route: Router) {
    route.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        let current_route = event.state.root.firstChild;
        this.page_title = current_route?.data.page_title;
        if (this.page_title == undefined) {
          alert('Please set page title for the routing')
        }
        else {
          titleService.setTitle(this.page_title);
        }

      }
    });
  }
}
```

You can also try to declare the service then copy the codes in the constructor to a function inside the service and do the necessary imports, After call the function of service inside constructor of **app.component.ts** which will help in future projects.

Answer (score 0):

## Angular version 14 (2022)

Just add a title key in the routes const. For instance

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

// Components
import {ViewHomeComponent} from "./components/home.component";


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home', component: ViewHomeComponent, title: 'Home' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export default class ModuleHomeRouting {}
```

That will set **automatically** the title to 'Home'!